# Ant compilation : How can I remove class files that I deleted in svn repository?

Tags: svn, ant, hudson

Using Hudson, I want to reflect deletion at the svn repo to the classpath.
In other words, When I deleted a java source codes and commit, then want to also delete classes related to the source codes via Ant.
Is there any possible solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We may need to see your ant script, but here a couple of things.

You `ant` build script should have an `clean` target (which should delete all generated files, which includes your classes).  If you have it, then so long as `hudson` runs this target, you should be fine.

If your `ant` script explicitly names specifies these classes (say, to create compile-time or runtime *classpath*), then the script should also be updated to exclude it.

Then again, none of these may be what you are looking for.

Comment: If there is no clean target, it can be emulated when using subversion, with unchecking "use update" this should delete your workspace when starting a job (or at least the folders that are used for checkout).